# Redownloading iBooks on an iPad 1st Gen

Tags: ipad, books, ios

I downloaded iBooks onto my iPad 1st Gen (Running 5.1.1) a long time ago (on a different Apple ID) and I just today deleted it and now I want it back. The App Store will only let me download the latest version, which doesn't work on my iPad. My usual route of getting the app on an older version of iTunes and re-downloading it on my iPad doesn't work because iBooks doesn't appear there, so I'm stuck. My iPad's jailbroken so I can install an .ipa.

Comment: Now, a reason why Apple Books doesn't work on your iPad could be because your device is jailbroken. Your best bet would be to restore from a backup that has Apple Books. You should note that this will probably get rid of the jailbreak. Also a side note, all iPads can install IPAs. In fact, iOS downloads apps from the App Store in IPA files. Normal iOS devices run only signed and verified IPAs, but jailbroken devices run any IPA. If you have a Mac, you can click "Get Info" for the IPA file and you will see that it says iOS Application Container.

Comment: iBooks worked perfectly with my jailbreak installed, it only disappeared because I deleted it and now I really want to use it.